# Java socks proxy uses local DNS

Tags: java, proxy, socks

I'm trying to connect to an oracle database through a SOCKS proxy, because I don't have direct access to the oracle server.
So, I open my proxy on port 4000, and add these options to my application:

```
-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=4000
```

Now, if I launch my app using oracle server's hostname in the connection string, then I get a "Unknown host specified".
If I use IP address instead of hostname, the connection is successful.
I guess java is trying to resolve the hostname using my local DNS instead of the remote one. How can I use the remote DNS?

Comment: which version of SOCKS is it using?  SOCKS4 required the client resolve the hostname.  SOCKS 4a provided a way to send the name to the server to resolve the IP address, and SOCKS5 also allows the server to resolve the name (whether or not it does this is specified by the client).

Comment: I'm using v5 (the default value for socksProxyVersion). You tell SOCKS5 allows the server to resolve the name. The problem is that currently my client is trying to resolve the name, so I get an exception.

Comment: What client is it?  One of the structural problems with SOCKS (e.g. if it's in a library hooked underneath a client) is that typically clients resolve DNS before making a connection, whereas with SOCKS the resolution and connection are done together in the same request.  Various auto-SOCKS clients get around this by hooking DNS lookups and returning bogus addresses (which they use to identify the original destination name when they see the connection request in SOCKS).

Comment: The client is a Java7 RE (JDBC connection).

Comment: Something is asking Java to make the connection.

Answer (score 3):

In the current OpenJDK implementation, you can use an unsupported workaround for this. It might be removed in future versions. The SOCKS implementation *does* support remote DNS lookup. However, this only works for unresolved InetSocketAddress objects. Unfortunately, the NetworkClient class, used by URL.openConnection, always tries to resolve an InetSocketAddress, even when SOCKS is used. You can use a trick to prevent local name resolution.

Set the (internal) system property jdk.net.hosts.file to a filename, by using the -Djdk.net.hosts.file=some_file command line parameter, or by setting the property from code early enough (first thing in main). This must be done before the internal NameService class initializer is executed, otherwise this won't work:

System.setProperty("jdk.net.hosts.file", "some_file");

In the current OpenJDK-based Java runtimes, this will change domain name resolution to this file instead of usual DNS. A missing entry or non-existing hostfile results in an unresolved InetSocketAddress. This is exactly what we need here, because the SOCKS implementation will use remote DNS now.

Mind however that the resolution of your proxy server won't work anymore, so you'll have to specify the IP-address of the proxy server instead. You could also add the proxy server to some_file. Other DNS resolutions you might need in your application, won't work either.

Comment: I don't think this works (anymore): `Unable to resolve host <redacted> in hosts file foo` for `-Djdk.net.hosts.file=foo`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028776) of the jvm and it seems that there is no immediate plan to fix it.

> SOCKS is really old. Not widely deployed in a modern infrastructure. Lowering priority to P4.

Comment: You mean there is *no* plan to fix it

Comment: @jaudo thanks for reminding,yes,you are right, a **no** was missed and I updated my answer.

Comment: As workaround, we can proxy DNS over SOCKS5 separately by additional software like [dns2socks](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dns2socks). JVM should be configured to use our custom DNS proxy via `-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers=127.0.0.1` and `-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,sun`